# How hide from menu content type Basic Page and Landing page

Tags: 8, nodes, navigation, configuration

In Drupal 8,  I tried to remove default **Basic page** and **Landing page** content types, but it have content related to them. So, my quick fix will to only hide those one from some user. I tried with permissions but it didn't work .

/admin/people/permissions
[image]
[image]
Updated: Same issue
[image]

But users with role **Content Publisher** and/or **Content Administrator** still see those CTs in /node/add

[image]

There is any other way to hide those ones?

Thanks

Edit:
This option was the issue **Create any content on assigned domains**
[image]

Comment: Do those roles have the _Administer content_ permission?

Comment: Is your problem about the content and structure that you don't need, or you do need that but want more control over permissions? Why not just delete the content of those types, they you can delete the content types as well?

Comment: @Clive Administer content was ticked, I removed check .. but have same result.

Comment: Are you logged in as user 1?

Comment: @Kevin no, I logged with a new user with role Content Publisher

Comment: That permission does not sound like core Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: 
I just removed for Content publisher or any other role

*Create any content on assigned domains* 
[image]

I think this permission was added with the module **Domain Access**